# Query with data from user in MSSQL with PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

(I'm forced to work on microsoft sql server in my internship).
I don't understand why my query doesn't work in PHP (it returns no data), but it works when I put it directly in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (it returns the datas).

Here is my code :

```
<?php 
  require('conn.php');

    if(isset($_POST['submit-search'])){
      $search = $_POST['search'];
      $sql = "SELECT codepo, codepsa, controle, FORMAT(date, 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss') as date FROM dbo.codebarre where datediff(day, date, '$search') = 0";
      var_dump($sql);
      $result = sqlsrv_query($conn2, $sql);
      $queryResult = sqlsrv_num_rows($result);

      ?>
    (...)
      <?php
      if($queryResult > 0){
        while($donnees = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          ?>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th style="font-weight: normal;"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($donnees['codepo']); ?></th>
            <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($donnees['codepsa']); ?></td>
            <td <?php if ($donnees['controle'] === 'NOK') {
                  echo 'style="color: red; font-weight: bold"';
                } ?>><?php echo htmlspecialchars($donnees['controle']);  ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $donnees['date'] ?></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <?php
        }
      } else {
        echo "No data";
      }
    }
```

The `var_dump($sql)` returns me this :

> string(138) "SELECT codepo, codepsa, controle, FORMAT(date,
> 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss') as date FROM dbo.codebarre where datediff(day,
> date, '20210107') = 0"

As I told you when I paste it in Management studio it works, so I don't understand why it doesn't here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sqlsrv\_num\_rows Not Returning Any Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741534/sqlsrv-num-rows-not-returning-any-value) . See also https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-num-rows.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- Execute `sqlsrv_query()` with the appropriate cursor type, if you want to get the exact number of the returned rows.
- Use `sqlsrv_has_rows()` if you want to check if there are rows returned.

PHP code using `sqlsrv_num_rows()`:

```
<?php
    
   ...
   $result = sqlsrv_query($conn2, $sql, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
   $queryResult = sqlsrv_num_rows($result);
   if ($queryResult > 0) {
       // Fetch data
   }

   ...
?>
```

PHP code using `sqlsrv_has_rows()`:

```
<?php
    
   ...
   $result = sqlsrv_query($conn2, $sql);
   $queryResult = sqlsrv_has_rows($result);
   if ($queryResult) {
       // Fetch data
   }

   ...
?>
```

As an additional note, always use parameterized statements to prevent possible SQL injection issues. As is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-query?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks), function `sqlsrv_query()` does both statement preparation and statement execution and can be used to execute parameterized queries.

```
<?php

    ...
    $sql = "
        SELECT codepo, codepsa, controle, FORMAT(date, 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss') AS date 
        FROM dbo.codebarre 
        WHERE datediff(day, date, ?) = 0
    ";
    $params = array($search);
    $options = array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn2, $sql, $params, $options);

...
?>
```