# Get Row Count For SQL Dataset in php Class Object

Tags: sql, object, oop, count, dataset

I've tried to find a good source of info for this but struggling.

I have a php class which gets a dataset from an SQL (Not MySQL) database.

I need to obtain a dataset row number.

The following is within a class method function:

```
$this->mat_sql_query = "SELECT * FROM WHATEVER";
$this->mat_sql_data = sqlsrv_query($this->sql_connection, $this->mat_sql_query);

$this->mat_sql_count= $this->mat_sql_data->num_rows;
        
if($this->mat_sql_count>0){
  echo "Got Data";
} else {
  echo "No data";
}
```

I've tried variations of sql_num_rows(), count() and num_rows but all fail for various reasons.

What is the method and syntax needed here please?

Comment: I've tried "$this->mat_sql_count = count($this->mat_sql_data);" but get "Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in......"

Comment: I've now also tried "$this->mat_sql_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($this->mat_sql_data);" but it doesn't return a value.

Comment: Just found the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741534/sqlsrv-num-rows-not-returning-any-value